# mongodb $aggregate empty array and multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

mongodb has below document:

```
> db.test.find({name:{$in:["abc","abc2"]}})
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "abc", "scores" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "abc2", "scores" : [ 10, 20 ] }
```

I want get **scores** array length for each document, how should I do?

Tried below command:

```
db.test.aggregate({$match:{name:"abc2"}}, {$unwind: "$scores"}, {$group: {_id:null, count:{$sum:1}}} )
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 2 }
```

But below command:

```
db.test.aggregate({$match:{name:"abc"}}, {$unwind: "$scores"}, {$group: {_id:null, count:{$sum:1}}} )
```

Return Nothing. Question:

1. How should I get each lenght of scores in 2 or more document in one
   command?
2. Why the result of second command return nothing? and how
   should I check if the array is empty?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So this is actually a common problem. The result of the [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) phase in an aggregation pipeline where the array is "empty" is to "remove" to document from the pipeline results.

In order to return a count of "0" for such an an "empty" array then you need to do something like the following.

In MongoDB 2.6 or greater, just use [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/):

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": "abc" } },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": null,
       "count": { "$sum": { "$size": "$scores" } }
    }}
])
```

In earlier versions you need to do this:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "name": "abc" } },
    { "$project": {
        "name": 1,
        "scores": {
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$scores", [] ] },
                { "$const": [false] },
                "$scores"
            ]
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$scores" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "count": { "$sum": {
            "$cond": [
                "$scores",
                1,
                0
            ]
        }}
    }}
])
```

The modern operation is simple since `$size` will just "measure" the array. In the latter case you need to "replace" the array with a single `false` value when it is empty to avoid `$unwind` "destroying" this for an "empty" statement.

So replacing with `false` allows the [**`$cond`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) "trinary" to choose whether to add `1` or `0` to the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) of the overall statement.

That is how you get the length of "empty arrays".

Comment: @Michael The OP took the trouble of "trying something" So I think that is a nice thing to reward as well.

Comment: @NeilLunn Very quick & precise answer! Just tried in my project it's worked except a typo: `db.test.aggregate({ ` should be `db.test.aggregate([ `

Comment: _New in version 3.2_ of mongodb we have `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` which prevents removing items with empty array from the pipeline result. `$unwind: {
          path: '$someArray',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        }`

Answer (score 6):

To get the length of scores in 2 or more documents you just need to change the `_id` value in the **[`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline which contains the distinct group by key, so in this case you need to group by the document `_id`.

Your second aggregation returns nothing because the **[`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** query pipeline passed a document which had an empty scores array. To check if the array is empty, your match query should be

`{'scores.0': {$exists: true}}` or `{scores: {$not: {$size: 0}}}`
Overall, your aggregation should look like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": {"scores.0": { "$exists": true } } },
    { "$unwind": "$scores" },
    {
        "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I think the overall point here was to get a `0` count "as well as others". But this does make a valid point to "filtering" `0` length arrays

Comment: You are right, from the way the OP structured the questions I got the impression that he needs to "filter" empty arrays earlier in the aggregation especially in the second question.

Comment: My "impression" was that they "wanted" the `0` and `$unwind` "Destroyed" that. Hence the form of the answer I gave. All points are learning points.

Comment: @NeilLunn, yes it is, the key is `$unwind` here cannot get `0 length array`. But @chridam also gave a good `scores.0` solution to get array size, except the `0 length array`.